# Plot polygon with ggmap in R

Tags: r, polygon, ggmap

I want to plot a Polygon in a map. For this I use ggmap at the moment, but it doesnt let me do it giving me always an error message:

> Fehler: ggplot2 none-numeric argument for binary Operator

My code looks like this:

```
> library(rgdal)
> library(geojsonio)
> library(sp)
> library(maps)
> library(ggmap)
> library(maptools)

> data_file <- "/home/jan/Downloads/map.geojson"

> data_json <- geojson_read(data_file, what = "sp")

> plot(data_json, usePolypath = FALSE)

> mapImage <- ggmap(get_googlemap(c(lon = -118.243683, lat = 34.052235), scale = 1, 
+                                 zoom = 7), extent = "normal")
Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=34.052235,-118.243683&zoom=7&size=640x640&scale=1&maptype=terrain&sensor=false

> dat <- as.data.frame(data_json)

> names(data)[1:2] <- c("lon","lat")

> print(mapImage)+
+   geom_polygon(data = dat, aes(lon, lat), colour="red", fill="red")

Fehler in print(mapImage) + geom_polygon(data = dat, aes(lon, lat), colour = "red",  : 
  nicht-numerisches Argument für binären Operator
```

but if I do

```
> dat2 <- as.numeric(dat)

> print(mapImage)+
+   geom_polygon(data = dat2, aes(lon, lat), colour="red", fill="red")
Fehler: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

I get the error

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

PS. Iḿ very new to R and programming

Thank you

Comment: `ggplot` needs a dataframe (class="list") as its data argument. The code is not reprodicble. We don't have access to `/home/jan/Downloads/map.geojson`. Read [MCVE] and "How to make a great reproducible example in R".

Comment: If you want interactive maps, both `leaflet` and `googleway` support mapping `GeoJSON` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
data_json <- geojson_read(data_file, what = "sp")
```

returns an `sp` class object, which `ggplot` and `geom_polygon` can't deal with.

The fix is to run `fortify` on it to make a data frame that `geom_polygon` can use. You've not supplied us with your data file so we can't give you the exact code, but:

```
data_file <- system.file("examples", "california.geojson", package = "geojsonio")
data_json <- geojson_read(data_file, what = "sp")
fd = fortify(data_json)
mapImage + geom_polygon(data=fd, aes(x=long,y=lat))
```

should give you enough clues.